# Lasso features selection through Crossvalidation

Tags: regression, cross-validation, lasso

I took a method to determine the best features for a classifier from somewhere and I wanted to ask if it is reliable or not:

I was trying to, very simply, select the best features for a Logistic Regression classifier.

Using **Lasso().coef_** it turned out that everytime I switched the training and testing data indexs (with a random ShuffleSplit, so in a CrossValidation process), the *0 lasso coefs changed*. So, to visualize it:

```
Loop1    
random_seed=1
Lasso_coefs_obtained = [0,   0.9, 0,  0,   0.1]

Loop2
random_seed=2
Lasso_coefs_obtained = [0.3, 0,   0,  0.7, 0  ]

Loop3
random_seed=3
Lasso_coefs_obtained = [0.1, 0.8, 0,  0.2, 0.2]
```

In order to determine if a feature coefficient was really null, I would sum the three coefficients lists and determine the 0 elements (which must be those elements that are 0 in the three lists).

```
Sum_coefs = [0.4, 1.7, 0,  0.9, 0.3]
```

In my case, I did this method with 10 loops (I have 10 coefficients lists over 72 variables). After 10 loops, only 55 coefficients remain non-zero. So, I delated 17 features for the classifier.

**Is this method reliable or I'm just making up an algorithm with no guarantees?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Clarifying your approach

> the 0 lasso coefs changed

What value of $\lambda$ (the Lasso parameter) did you use and how did you determine it ? Your approach seems confusing:

- Have you performed k-fold cross validation on your training set for a range of $\lambda$ values and chosen the $\lambda$  that gives the best results ?
- I would suggest starting with cross validation without replacement so as to avoid a kind of bootstrapping effect (i.e. careful with the shufflesplit)

A good introduction to combining Lasso and cross validation is provided by the inventor of the Lasso, *Robert Tibshirani*, **pages 15 and 16 [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/datamining/lectures/18-val1.pdf)**. Also here: [Lasso cross validation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69549/lasso-cross-validation) and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_lasso_model_selection.html)

[image]

---

### Some reasons for why Lasso coefficients would be different

- **Wrong approach**: if you only use the default $\lambda$ value of your algorithm (e.g. from R or Sklearn), mix up the data set with replacement and perform Lasso you are likely going to obtain different parameter values.
- **Too few data points**: if your data set is too small, or if $K$ of the K-fold CV is too large, your model will be fitted on a data set which is not representative of the overall data set, which would explain different results across the folds
- **More features than data points**: CV and Lasso are unstable in this case
- **Unstable model or extreme collinearity**: If you use a standard approach to select features but still get different coefficients, my intuition is that your features are so highly correlated that they cause the algorithm to struggle / encounter numerical issues / become unstable

**Some additional sources on the topic**:

- An entire thesis on Lasso and CV instability [here](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/38874/KineVeronicaLund_MasterThesis.pdf?sequence=1)
- https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016794731300323X

---

### Bootstrapping

Provided that none of the above issues apply, bootstrapping your data set and performing standard k-fold CV can still be useful

- You will need to repeat the boostrap experiment hundreds or thousands of times (not 10)
- You can perform statistical inference on the bootstrap results such as a bootstrapped confidence intervals, statistical significance tests etc..
- Careful when interpreting these results however, as bootstrap inference has its own limitations, bias and interpretation issues (a non trivial topic - look on stackexchange)